# Unit testing the repository - Does it look right?

Tags: unit-testing, repository

So, this is my first try into Unit Testing and i'm just wondering if i'm doing it right cause it kinda feels like i'm fooling myself so, any sugestions and/or feedback is welcome, thank you :)

```
[TestClass]
public class ArticleRepositoryTest
{
    IArticleRepository _articleRepository;

    const string drawingNumber = "drawingNumber";
    const string searchString = "searchString";
    const string articleDescription = "I have a description";
    ArticleDTO articleDTO = new ArticleDTO() { DrawingNumber = drawingNumber };

    [TestInitialize]
    public void Initialize()
    {
        //Arange
        _articleRepository = A.Fake<IArticleRepository>();

        A.CallTo(() => _articleRepository.GetAll()).Returns(new List<ArticleDTO>());
        A.CallTo(() => _articleRepository.GetOne(drawingNumber)).Returns(new ArticleDTO { DrawingNumber = drawingNumber });
        A.CallTo(() => _articleRepository.GetSearch(searchString)).Returns(new List<ArticleDTO>());
        A.CallTo(() => _articleRepository.SaveData(articleDTO)).Invokes(call => { _articleRepository.GetAll().Result.Add(articleDTO); });
        A.CallTo(() => _articleRepository.Edit(articleDTO)).Invokes(call => _articleRepository.GetOne(drawingNumber).Result.ArticleDescr = articleDescription);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Article_GetAll_ReturnsListOfArticleDTO()
    {
        //Arange - Done in the Initialize() method.
        //Act
        var articlesDTO = _articleRepository.GetAll();
        //Assert
        Assert.IsInstanceOfType(articlesDTO, typeof(Task<ICollection<ArticleDTO>>));
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Article_GetOneByDrawingNumber_ReturnsArticleDTO()
    {
        //Arange - Done in the Initialize() method.
        //Act
        var articleDTO = _articleRepository.GetOne(drawingNumber);
        //Assert
        Assert.IsInstanceOfType(articleDTO, typeof(Task<ArticleDTO>));
        Assert.AreEqual(drawingNumber, articleDTO.Result.DrawingNumber);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Article_GetSearch_ReturnsListOfArticleDTO()
    {
        //Arange - Done in the Initialize() method.
        //Act
        var articlesDTO = _articleRepository.GetSearch(searchString);
        //Assert
        Assert.IsInstanceOfType(articlesDTO, typeof(Task<ICollection<ArticleDTO>>));
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public async Task Article_SaveData_SavesTheArticleToTheDatabase()
    {
        //Arange - the repository and the articleDTO variable is set up in the Initialize() method.

        //Act
        _articleRepository.SaveData(articleDTO);
        //Assert
        A.CallTo(() => _articleRepository.SaveData(articleDTO)).MustHaveHappened();
        var list = await _articleRepository.GetAll();
        Assert.AreEqual(1, list.Count);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Article_Edit_EditsAnInstanceOfArticle()
    {
        //Arange - the repository and the articleDTO variable is set up in the Initialize() method.

        //Act
        articleDTO.ArticleDescr = articleDescription;
        _articleRepository.Edit(articleDTO);
        var x = _articleRepository.GetOne(drawingNumber).Result.ArticleDescr;
        //Assert
        A.CallTo(() => _articleRepository.Edit(articleDTO)).MustHaveHappened();
        Assert.AreEqual(articleDescription, x);
    }
```

Also, should i build a UnitOfWork class as well? And can you give some arguments there? Thank you.

Comment: You did UTs but non of them test the repository. Each one of your UTs verify that `FakeItEasy` works properly. Please add the concrete implementation of `IArticleRepository` which is the class you want to test(CUT - class under test)

Comment: but wouldn't that be an integration test then? Sorry for late answer, been on hollyday, i did found something about it around here somewhere but i can't find it again to post it here, long story short, i am fooling myself (as you also pointed out). There is no point in unit testing the repository because there's nothing to fake, so yes, as you mentioned, i should write integration tests for the repository and unit tests for anything relying on it.

Comment: Never mind, I hope your vacation was great! When you perform a UT on a method you are simulate a situation and then you verify that your unit behave exactly as you expected. In your case you don't have a unit at all, you override the unit behaviour with `FakeItEasy`, simulate a behaviour(on the fake object) and then verify that the behaviour occurred. Working with the concrete impl' of `IArticleRepository` is not mean your tests are integration tests. Your tests will be an integration tests if you won't isolate the concrete impl' of `IArticleRepository` from externals dependencies